# Restart GitHub completely?

Tags: git, github

I keep getting the errors

```
fatal: 'gits' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I think I mistyped git to gits, ran it, and now its an error that won't go away. Is there anyway I can completely restart GitHub? I'm trying to simply add code I had on my computer to git hub, and then put it on Heroku.  If I messed up bad, I'd rather just restart the GitHub process. Nothing I would feel bad for loosing.

I tried: GitHub reset --hard, but it didn't seem to do much?

Comment: In the spirit of https://xkcd.com/1597/, rename the folder, clone the repository again, and start fresh. :)

Comment: @Mary rename the folder? on GitHub?

Comment: No, on your local machine. And clone from Github again. Your link to the remote repository seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check that your origin is set by running

```
git remote -v
```

This should show you all of the push / fetch remotes for the project.

If this returns with no output, skip to last code block.

**Verify remote name / address**

If this returns showing that you have remotes set, check that the name of the remote matches the remote you are using in your commands.

```
$git remote -v
myOrigin ssh://git@example.com:1234/repo.git (fetch)
myOrigin ssh://git@example.com:1234/repo.git (push)
```

## this will fail because `origin` is not set

```
$git push origin master
```

## you need to use

```
$git push myOrigin master
```

If you want to rename the remote or change the remote's URL, you'll want to first remove the old remote, and then add the correct one.

**Remove the old remote**

```
$git remote remove myOrigin
```

**Add missing remote**

You can then add in the proper remote using

```
$git remote add origin ssh://git@example.com:1234/repo.git
```

## this will now work as expected

```
$git push origin master
```